# Kotlin: JSON Schema type "number" gets converted to String when using JSONObject(String)

Tags: android, json, kotlin, jsonschema, everit

I implemented a function to validate a given JSONObject against a given JSON Schema JSONObject.

Here is the code:

```
class JsonSchemaUtilsTest {
    //a JSON as a String
    val testJsonStr : String =
            """
            {
                "duration": 28298080890890809809
            }
            """.trimIndent()

    //The JSON schema as a String
    val testJsonSchemaStr : String =
            """
                {
                  "${'$'}schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "duration": {
                      "type": "number",
                    }

                  },
                  "required": [
                    "duration"
                  ]
                }
            """.trimIndent()
    @Test
    public fun test() {
        val json : JSONObject = JSONObject(testJsonStr)
        val schemaJson : JSONObject = JSONObject(testJsonSchemaStr)
        var boolean : Boolean = JsonSchemaUtils.validate(json, schemaJson)
        //The following line fails with "org.everit.json.schema.ValidationException: #/duration: expected type: Number, found: String"
        Assert.assertTrue("json validates against schemaJson", boolean)

    }
}
```

Im using the https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema library.

So somehow the given Number `"duration": 28298080890890809809` is converted to a String when using the `JSONObject(String)` constructor.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your input is bigger than maximum long value. Maximum long value is +9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Comment: Thanks @mehmetsalimayan that solved it :).